# Threshold for questions on facebook.stackoverflow.com

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined, stack-overflow, facebook

I have been seeing a lot of really off topic questions for Facebook on the regular SO. Some of the users are FB users seeking support for FB.

I feel it confuses legacy SO users.

Could we have the questions blocked for low ranked users on good old SO until at least X number of up votes or high quality answers? Mods could also force this on.

Just a thought...

Comment: i would appreciate some comments instead of blanket down votes.

Comment: SO endured the end-of-summer-school deluge the past few weeks.  Cr*ppy question are forever though.  Gotta whack the FB crowd into shape somehow.  It seems important.

Comment: well the problem is that they are average fb users...

Comment: such as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7225161/hijacked-profile

Comment: Go to your profile, click Prefs, add facebook* to your Ignored Tags.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're operating on the premise that facebook.stackoverflow.com != stackoverflow.com.

The questions on facebook.stackoverflow.com are a **subset** of the questions on stackoverflow.com.  If a question appears on facebook.stackoverflow.com, it appears on stackoverflow.com.

The users on facebook.stackoverflow.com are a **subset** of the users on stackoverflow.com.

So, aside from the premise being flawed and it not happening, what good would this do?  All it would do is hide questions from experienced users that need to see them in order to self-police the community.  The questions sitting around and not getting dealt with would not improve things.  It wouldn't educate new users.

The same quality checks and question/answer blocks that exist on stackoverflow.com exist on facebook.stackoverflow.com - because they are, at the root, the same site.  Downvoting, flagging, and voting to close is the appropriate action, just like on stackoverflow.com proper.

Answer (score 14):

Bad questions should be down voted and closed, not hidden from view.

Treating some tags ghettos would set a very bad precedent, so we're unlikely to ever do something like this.

Comment: Well the problem is that I'm not sure what rules apply on fb.

Comment: @Daniel - they are exactly the same as Stack Overflow.  Facebook Stack Overflow is a subset of Stack Overflow, not a different site.  Same users, same questions, same standards.